# Why won't MariaDB start after upgrade (NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)

Tags: debian, configuration, systemd, selinux, mariadb

After upgrade of my debian(testing, jessie to stretch) server on DigitalOcean, MariaDB won't start with *service mariadb start*.

I tried to purge all mariadb-* and mysql-* packages, delete configs and data, and reinstall them, but mariadb-server-10.1.21-5 refuses to be configured:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.21-5) ...
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-02-09 21:25:27 CET; 10ms ago
  Process: 1696 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
  Process: 1589 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1584 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1582 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1696 (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)

Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1696]: mariadb.service: Failed at step NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES spawning /usr/sbin/mysqld: Invalid argument
Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES
Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 21:25:27 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 10.1.21-5); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

this is the output of *journalctl -xe* after I try to start the service:

```
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/mariadb.service, ignoring: Operation not supported
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[7114]: mariadb.service: Failed at step NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES spawning /usr/sbin/mysqld: Invalid argument
-- Subject: Process /usr/sbin/mysqld could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The process /usr/sbin/mysqld could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 22.
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 05:10:52 cddssh systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

mysql error log has no errors/warnings.

I can start the mysqld binary just fine by itself.

I tried to follow instructions at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/upgrade-10116maria-1jessie-broke-system/ but then I get error

> mariadb.service: Failed at step NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES spawning /usr/sbin/mysqld: Invalid argument

It seems it has something to do with selinux as I found these lines in /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service

```
# Doesn't yet work properly with SELinux enabled
# NoNewPrivileges=true
```

Someone had a very similiar question on superuser but I do not understand what he did to solve it: https://superuser.com/questions/1103321/mariadb-server-broken-after-failed-package-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With help from #debian-next I found out the problem was probably in the digitalocean custom kernel.

Upon checking it turned out I was using a not very recent kernel – 3.2.0-4, but after selecting a more recent version from the web interface and rebooting it works OK.

Answer (score 5):

I can't upgrade the kernel (this is a vps).

I have found a solution :

edit `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

change `PrivateDevices=true` to `PrivateDevices=false`

Run `systemctl daemon-reload`

and `systemctl start mysql`

Comment: Don't edit the original systemd unit. Your changes will be lost on upgrade. Instead, [create an override](https://serverfault.com/q/840996/126632). This override will be preserved when you next upgrade the package.

Comment: thanks very much, you save my life.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with Debian 9.1 and MariaDB `10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1`. Seems it was also related to the kernel version. Updating kernel from `3.2.50` to `4.9.0-3-amd64` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the kernel as well (upgrade to 4.9.0-3-amd64); only I am running MariaDB in a Xen vm.

The kernel is taken of the Dom0 from the startup script, so even after an update, it still had the old kernel. Changing the script on the Dom0 solved the MariaDB problem.