# MariaDB fail to start (NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)

Tags: debian, configuration, systemd, selinux, mariadb

I have a similar problem that here :

[Why won't MariaDB start after upgrade (NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)](https://serverfault.com/questions/831503/why-wont-mariadb-start-after-upgrade-no-new-privileges)

But I can't upgrade the kernel (this is a vps).

Does someone have an idea ?